# Rigorous proof of continuity at a if and only if left and right limits equal f(a)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

My question is the following. I use a lot of times that a function is continuous at $a$ if and only if

$$\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x) = f(a) = \lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x) $$

But I've never found a rigorous proof (that I can still understand!). Maybe with $\epsilon - \delta$ definitions? Can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to write down the conditions for the left and right limit to exist and compare this to what you need in order that the limit exists?

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=f(a)$ means that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $$x\in (a,a+\delta_1)\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$

$\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)=f(a)$ means that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that $$x\in (a-\delta_2,a)\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$

Thus, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ such that

$$|x-a|\le \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon,$$ that is, $f$ is continuous at $a.$

Answer (score 1):

A map $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ only if $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$; but $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ iff $-\delta < x-a < 0$ and $0 < x-a < \delta$; hence $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff $\lim_{x \to a-}f(x) = f(a) = \lim_{x \to a+}f(x)$.